# .create() on mongoose schema erroring with "this expression is not callable" - TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, typescript, mongoose, next.js

My .create on a mongoose model is erroring and I cannot find out what the issue is. I'm using Next JS and the call is happening in an API route....

The get request works fine...

pages>API>task.tsx

```
import dbConnect from "../../util/dbconnect";
import Task from "../../models/Task";

dbConnect();

export default async function (req, res) {
  const { method } = req;
  switch (method) {
    case "GET":
      try {
        const tasks = await Task.find({});
        res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: tasks });
      } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).json({ success: false });
      }
      break;
    case "POST":
      try {
        const task = await Task.create(req.body);
        res.status(201).json({ success: true, data: task });
      } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).json({ success: false });
      }
      break;
    default:
      res.status(400).json({ success: false });
      break;
  }
}
```

THe error message reads

"This expression is not callable.
Each member of the union type '{ <DocContents = ITask | _AllowStringsForIds<Pick<Pick<_LeanDocument, "_id" | "__v" | "id" | "title" | "description" | "createdDate" | "estimatedDueDate" | "status">, "_id" | ... 6 more ... | "status">>>(doc: DocContents): Promise<...>; <DocContents = ITask | _AllowStringsForIds<...>>(docs: DocContents[], opt...' has  signatures, but none of those  signatures are compatible with each other.ts(2349)
"

The Schema is here:
models>Task.tsx

```
import mongoose, { Schema, Document, model, models } from "mongoose";

export interface ITask extends Document {
  title: string;
  description: string;
  createdDate: string;
  estimatedDueDate?: string;
  status: string[];
}

const TaskSchema: Schema = new Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Please add a title"],
    unique: true,
    trim: true,
    maxlength: [60, "Title cannot be more than 60 Characters "],
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Please add a title"],
    unique: true,
    trim: true,
    maxlength: [400, "Title cannot be more than 60 Characters"],
  },
  createdDate: {
    type: Date,
    required: [true],
  },
  estimatedDueDate: {
    type: Date,
    required: [
      false,
      "Entering a due date helps to create your visual timeline",
    ],
  },
  status: {
    type: String,
    required: [true],
    default: "New",
  },
});

export default models.Task || model<ITask>("Task", TaskSchema);
```

I have tried to change the .create() to  await new Task(req.body) - if I leave the req.body out, then the post works with an empty new document (which doesn't have all of the properties specified  in the Schema) if I leave req.body in the function call then it errors.

the repo is here:  https://github.com/jondhill333/ProjectManagementTool

Any help gratefully recieved!

Answer (score 1):

fixed it ... the post request needs to updated as below:

```
 case "POST":
      try {
        const task = await new Task(req.body);
        res.status(201).json({ success: true, data: task });
        task.save();
      } catch (error) {
        res
          .status(400)
          .json({ success: false + " post", message: error.message, error });
      }
```

Comment: ok.. ish

So the problem persists with Task.findByIdAndUpdate() - same error message as before - there is clearly something about Typescript Interfaces which I don't know which is the source of the problem. Its strange as I haven't seen this error in any tutorial I've been looking at for Typescript - these two functions have been able to be used, with exactly the same Interface/Schema format.

If you know tha answer please let me know and Ill post up on here once I find it.

Thanks!